# grails-spring-security-mock -> No bean named 'ldapAuthProvider' Errors is thrown

Tags: grails, spring-security, integration-testing, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I'm using the "[Mock authentication support for Spring Security](http://zirbes.org/grails-spring-security-mock/docs/guide/index.html)" with the following configuration:

1. Grails 2.3.2
2. JDK 1.6
3. spring-security-core:1.2.7.3
4. spring-security-mock:1.0.3

My Config.groovy has the following entries ->

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
        'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
        'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider',
        'daoAuthenticationProvider',
        'ldapAuthProvider']

grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.active = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.usernameMapper.userDnBase = false

//Configuration changes to accommodate plugin for mocking spring security
grails.plugins.springsecurity.mock.active = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.mock.fullName = 'User A'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.mock.email = 'user_a@gmail.com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.mock.username = 'user_a'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.mock.roles = ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']
grails.plugins.springsecurity.mock.load.dao = false
```

However, when I run my Integration Test (extends spock.lang.Specification) I get the following Error ->
***Fatal error running tests: No bean named 'ldapAuthProvider' is defined (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ldapAuthProvider' is defined***

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ldap - there's no support for LDAP in the core plugin.

Comment: Plus it's disabled with `grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.active = false` - no beans are registered if the plugin isn't active. That's true for all of the Spring Security plugins (or at least the once I wrote)